# Escanear código y mostrar información en pantalla con PHP,MySql y Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Bueno en realidad no tengo mucha experiencia en programacion apenas voy iniciando en el mundo y me enfrento a este problema de ir pidiendo informacion de mi bd mediante un lector de escaner y agregarlo a una tabla de informacion cada vez que se escanee un nuevo elemento se vaya agregando a la lista.

**Busqueda.php**

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$base_datos = 'netapp';
$usuario = 'root';
$clave = '';
/* Dos métodos de poner el juego de caracteres en utf-8 */
$conexion = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=${servidor};dbname=${base_datos};charset=utf8",
  $usuario,
  $clave,
  [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
  ]
);
/* No es necesario y no es recomendable hacerlo así */
/*$conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");*/
/* Preparamos la consulta SQL */
$res = $conexion->prepare('
  SELECT *
  FROM caratulasalida
  WHERE dn = :codigo
');
/* Asignamos el parámetro al valor enviado por POST */
$res->bindValue(
  ':codigo',
  $_POST['codigo'],
  PDO::PARAM_STR
);
/* Ejecutamos la consulta */
$res->execute();
/* Devolvemos el registro obtenido como respuesta en JSON */
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

**listado.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <form id="codigobarras">
      <input type="text" name="codigo" value="" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <table id="tabla">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>net_app_po</th>
                <th>customer_np</th>
                <th>qty</th>
                <th>rev</th>
                <th>boxes_by_po</th>
                <th>dn</th>
                <th>create_date_asn</th>
                <th>shipping_address</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>so_number</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="registros">

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    /* Tras cargar el documento posicionamos el cursor en el lector de código de barras */
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let codigobarras = document.getElementById('codigobarras');
    /* Ponemos el foco en el campo "codigo" */
    codigobarras.codigo.focus();
    /* Capturamos el evento de envío de formulario (pulsar ENTER o pulsar Enviar) */
    codigobarras.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    /* Evitamos el envío real del formulario */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Hacemos la llamada al API (busqueda.php o el API de ejemplo) */
    $.ajax( "busqueda.php" )
    .done(function(datos) {
        /* Depuramos los datos recibidos */
        console.log( datos );
        /* Si no se devolvió ningún registro (false) debería hacerse algo */
        if (datos === false) {
            /* hacer algo */
            return;
        }
        /* Agregamos una fila con los datos obtenidos */
        $('#registros').append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.id ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.net_app_po ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.customer_np ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.qty ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.rev ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.boxes_by_po ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.dn ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.create_date_asn ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.shipping_address ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.description ))
            .append($('<td>').append( datos.so_number ))
        );
    })
    .fail(function() {
            alert( "Error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        /* Seleccionamos el texto para que se pueda sobreescribir por la siguiente lectura */
        $("input[name='codigo']").select();
    });
    });
    }, false);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

y para hacer limpieza de la pagina y agregar nuevos elemento al otro dia por asi decirlo utilizar un boton.
espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: Solo preocupate por hacer la web bien, el scanner o lector de barras lo unico que hará es leer el codigo y escribirlo en pantalla, para lo cual al momento de leer tendras que estar ubicado en el input text que recibira el codigo. Algunos scanners pueden configurar para enviar la tecla ENTER de modo que podrías eventar el campo para que al recibir el evento envie el formulario

Comment: Tal y como te ha dicho @JonnathanQ , no hay que desarrollar nada especial en una web para soportar la integración con un lector de código de barras. Estos dispositivos simulan la pulsación por teclado del código leído y, opcionalmente, envían un retorno del carro para indicar el final de la lectura. Lo más importante es posicionar el cursor en el campo apropiado para que las pulsaciones llegan a éste. Para ello puedes usar, por ejemplo, [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias por sus respuestas y por tomarse el tiempo ya e echo un poco mejor mi web para hacer el ingreso de datos y ya empese a usar focus() para que se autoposicione el cursor y solo escanear, el detalle queria una poca de orientacion en JQuery y Ajax para hacer el llamado de los datos desde mi bd y posicionarlos en mi web. pero agradesco su aportacion buen dia

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con el elemento que obtendrá el foco (en el que va el código de barras) y te agrego código.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya quedo editado el input con el autofocus donde va el codigo de barras, segun yo solo es hacer las consultas a la bd es un simple where y que jale los datos y los ponga en la tabla pero eso es lo que no se como hacerlo que a como escanees ponga uno tras otro

Comment: @fokus, ¿podrías indicarnos qué campo de la tabla relaciona un producto con su código de barras?

Comment: @OscarGarcia eso es todo lo que tengo, a mis capasidades solo logro mostrar lo que contiene la bd mediante el while es algo sensillo lo se pero ocupo que solo se me muestren los codigos q voy escaneando uno tras otro como si fuera una registradora de productos por ejem, segun yo se puede hacer con la consulta y a la consulta asigarnela la variable del dato que se va a escanear en este caso seria por (DN), pero igual ahi esta la tabla de los datos

Comment: Si no me dices el campo de la tabla de la base de datos que contiene el código de barras no podré ayudarte porque un `SELECT` sin un `WHERE` obtiene todos los registros de la tabla, y lo que intento es que únicamente obtenga aquél producto cuyo código de barras acabamos de escanear.

Comment: @OscarGarcia 

<?php
require 'conexion.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM caratulasalida where DN";
$res = $conexion->query($sql);
?>

Comment: ¿PDO/MySQL o mysqli?

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya esta todo el codigo tal y como lo tengo asta el momento, espero me puedas apoyar con el problema que tengo

Comment: Siento la tardanza @fokus , me pongo con ello.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya edite de nuevo la pregunta disculpa como te comento soy nuevo en esta pagina y no conosco bien las reglas y todo eso, como te comentaba adapte lo que me pasaste a lo que devo de tener pero aun asi no me muetra solo me aparece un false

Comment: @OscarGarcia Hola espero que estes bien me podrias ayudar con un problema sobre esta pregunta... cambio el modo de hacerlo y ando poco mas bien muy perdido

Comment: Si has cambiado la forma de hacerlo deberías crear una pregunta nueva describiendo lo mejor posible la nueva forma. Déjame el enlace por aquí cuando la crees y echo un vistazo.

Comment: hola @OscarGarcia espero que estes bien, si no es mucha molestia me podrias ayudar con este tema por favor
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174898/como-puedo-validar-input-text-sin-usar-boton-con-php-mysql

Comment: Por casualidad qué lector de barras usas o qué marca es ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Descripción de la solución

Necesitamos conseguir lo siguiente:

- Configuración del lector de códigos de barras para que genere una pulsación de <kbd>ENTER</kbd> tras enviar el código de barras escaneado (está fuera del ámbito de esta pregunta y de stackoverflow). Usaremos un ejemplo precargado de comida (EAN 8410100064932) y/o una serie de TV (EAN 0883929072552).
- Configurar en la página un elemento de un formulario que obtenga el foco inmediatamente tras cargar la página.
- Capturar el evento de envío del formulario anterior para realizar la petición al servidor de obtención de datos.
- Realizar la búsqueda del artículo por su código de barras en la base de datos y devolver los datos en un formato fácilmente interpretable por javascript (JSON).
- Analizar el resultado obtenido para actualizar la tabla de productos (agregar un `<tr>`/`<td>` al `<tbody>`).

La protección [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) del navegador suele ser suficiente para evitar un uso externo del API REST que vas a crear, pero quizá deberías plantearte protecciones adicionales como que sólo los usuarios registrados (con sesión iniciada) puedan realizar esas consultas, etc.

### Código HTML

```js
/* Tras cargar el documento posicionamos el cursor en el lector de código de barras */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let codigobarras = document.getElementById('codigobarras');
  /* Ponemos el foco en el campo "codigo" */
  codigobarras.codigo.focus();
  /* Capturamos el evento de envío de formulario (pulsar ENTER o pulsar Enviar) */
  codigobarras.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    /* Evitamos el envío real del formulario */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Hacemos la llamada al API (busqueda.php o el API de ejemplo) */
    $.ajax({
      url: 'busqueda.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        codigo: codigobarras.codigo.value,
      },
    })
    .done(function(datos) {
      /* Depuramos los datos recibidos */
      console.log( datos );
      /* Si no se devolvió ningún registro (false) debería hacerse algo */
      if (datos === false) {
        /* hacer algo */
        alert('No se encontró el código de barras');
        return;
      }
      /* Agregamos una fila con los datos obtenidos */
      $('#registros').append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>').append( datos.DN ))
        .append($('<td>').append( datos.model_name ))
      );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
      /* Seleccionamos el texto para que se pueda sobreescribir por la siguiente lectura */
      $("input[name='codigo']").select();
    });
  });
}, false);
```

```css
#tabla {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tabla th, #tabla td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#tabla th:first-child, #tabla td:first-child {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="codigobarras">
  <input type="text" name="codigo" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="registros">
    <tr>
      <td>8410100064932</td>
      <td>Comida</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0883929072552</td>
      <td>Serie TV</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Código PHP

El contenido de `busqueda.php` podría ser:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$base_datos = 'nea';
$usuario = 'root';
$clave = '';
/* Dos métodos de poner el juego de caracteres en utf-8 */
$conexion = new PDO(
  "mysql:host=${servidor};dbname=${base_datos};charset=utf8",
  $usuario,
  $clave,
  [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
  ]
);
/* No es necesario y no es recomendable hacerlo así */
/*$conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");*/
/* Preparamos la consulta SQL */
$res = $conexion->prepare('
  SELECT *
  FROM caratulasalida
  WHERE DN = :codigo
');
/* Asignamos el parámetro al valor enviado por POST */
$res->bindValue(
  ':codigo',
  $_POST['codigo'],
  PDO::PARAM_STR
);
/* Ejecutamos la consulta */
$res->execute();
/* Devolvemos el registro obtenido como respuesta en JSON */
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

En caso de que no exista ningún registro con el código de barras enviado se entregará como respuesta un `false` que debería ser comprobado por javascript para mostrar un mensaje al usuario informándole de ese problema.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia por la ayuda me sale un pequeño error en el archivo de busqueda.php 
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: codigo in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\NeA\php\conexion.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
false
en la linea 22 tengo esto $res->bindValue(
  ':codigo',
  $_POST['codigo'],
  PDO::PARAM_STR
);

ya busque sobre bindValue en la libreria de php para entender como funciona y si esta muy bien. pero no me arroja el Json y al momento de hacer la busqueda no me arroja nada  me sale una ventana que tengo error en mi localhost

Comment: El archivo `busqueda.php` sólo funciona llamado desde jQuery por POST, ese error te sale por no existir el campo que deberías haber enviado desde allí. Si quieres te lo adapto para poder usarlo por GET.

Comment: asi como me lo pasaste lo deje solo modifique los campos de los cuales mando llamar y que se posicionaran en <tr><td>, te muestro como lo tengo con los pequeños cambios que hice.

Comment: He intentado invitarte a un chat de stackoverflow, pero no tienes aún suficiente reputación para usarlo :'(

Comment: si lo que pasa es que soy aun nuevo en esto, y casi no tengo post ni mucho menos ayudas a los demas y por eso no sube mi reputacion :(

Comment: No te preocupes, con paciencia irás subiendo. Hacer buenas preguntas se valora con 5 puntos por voto positivo y otros tantos cuando marcas una respuesta como correcta. ¿Te funcionó o sigue sin ir bien?

Comment: sigue sin ir bien @OscarGarcia, jajaj y mi pregunta tiene -2, lo que segun yo la logica que se debe hacer es hacer la consulta asignarle una variable donde va a cachar el dato que se escanee para hacer la peticion a la bd y asi poner la informacion en la tabla... pero el detalle que no se como plasmar eso en codigo :( tengo muy poco haciendo esto y asta donde te mostre la vez pasada es asta donde me dan por el momento mis conocimientos

Comment: Tienes 3 votos positivos (uno mío) y tres negativos (probablemente del comienzo, cuando no facilitaste datos). Si agregas la definición de tu tabla podré agregar unos registros de prueba y podré reproducir y poner en marcha el código. Usa `SHOW CREATE TABLE caratulasalida`.

Comment: aqui tienes datos, caratulasalida | CREATE TABLE `caratulasalida`(`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`net_app_po` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`customer_np` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`qty` int(20) NOT NULL,`rev` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`boxes_by_po` int(20) NOT NULL,`dn` int(20) NOT NULL,`create_date_asn` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`shipping_address` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,  `description` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,`so_number` int(11) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

Comment: Ya he encontrado el fallo. Con las prisas y programando de memoria olvidé incluir los datos del envío en la petición `.ajax`.

Comment: muchas gracias @OscarGarcia ya quedo perfecto como me lo imaginaba, y sabes ayer q estube tratando de solucionarlo que no encontraba estaba casi seguro de que hacia falta ahi pero ese casi fue el detalle pero muchas muchas gracias encerio, aun faltan mas detalles pero espero poder solucionarlos

Comment: De nada, un placer. Si necesitas ayuda con otra cosa abre nueva pregunta y, si quieres, déjame un mensaje por aquí para que la vea pronto.

Comment: solo tengo que hacer una validacion de que si se escanea dos veces el mismo numero no se agrege a la lista. muy bien muchas gracias por el apoyo... me imagino que la devo de poner en esta parte vdd ?? if (datos === false) {
        /* hacer algo */
        alert('No se encontró el código de barras');
        return;
      }

Comment: No, no. Yo lo haría incluso antes de enviar la petición `.ajax`. Guardaría un registro de los códigos de barras agregados y haría ahí la comprobación.

Comment: Guardar un registro de los codigos ?? seria algo mas o menos asi .... var registros= " "; if("input[name='codigo']"=="input[name='codigo']"){ alert "No se puede agregar codigos repetidos"; return }if("input[name='codigo']"!="input[name='codigo']"){ aqui no se como plasmar para que se agrege  }, pero creo que mas o menos asi seria

Comment: Para no "ensuciar" más esta pregunta abre una nueva con el código que llevas hasta ahora y lo que has intentado hacer para evitar repetidos (aunque no te funcione). Con gusto te echaré una mano de nuevo.

Comment: ya tengo 23 puntos ya me puedes incluir en el chat xD... tambien te agrege en la nueva pregunta

Comment: te agrege en la nueva pregunta @OscarGarcia