# como puedo validar input text sin usar boton con PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Buen dia espero me puedan ayudar con el problema que tengo sobre la validacion de este input text... tengo 2 tablas de base de datos y necesito hacer la validacion de dos campos en una tabla y un campo de otra tabla... el detalle es que escaneo un codigo de barras y que ya tengo registrado en mi bd y al mismo otro campo de estatus donde es 2 no pasa o 3 si pasa , entonces necesito que al momento de escanear cualquier codigo compruebe que tiene estatus 3 y al mismo tiempo que ese codigo que escanee este en la otra tabla que es lo que se proceso en el dia entonces en pocas palabras....

```
 **busqueda.php**

    <?php
    $servidor = 'localhost';
    $base_datos = 'net';
    $usuario = 'root';
    $clave = '';
    /* Dos métodos de poner el juego de caracteres en utf-8 */
    $conexion = new PDO(
      "mysql:host=${servidor};dbname=${base_datos};charset=utf8",
      $usuario,
      $clave,
      [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"]
    );

    /* Preparamos la consulta SQL */
    $res = $conexion->prepare('SELECT id, dn, if(pallet_status>=3, "3","2") FROM caratulasalida WHERE dn = :codigo ');
    /* Asignamos el parámetro al valor enviado por POST */
    $res->bindValue(':codigo', $_POST['codigo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    /* Ejecutamos la consulta */
    $res->execute();
    /* Devolvemos el registro obtenido como respuesta en JSON */
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    ?>
```

**index.html**

```
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3>Cabecera de la ventana</h3>
             </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>por fin apareci ahora si ya ponme lo que quieras hacer...</p>
             </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar</a>
             </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#codigo").keypress(function(even) {
                //Si fue enter
                //no se 3 es 13 if(even.which == 3) {
                  if(even.which == 13) {
                   //Como tu input lo tienes en un formulario, cuando oprimes enter sometes el formulario y te recarga la página, con esto puedes evitar eso.
                   $("#codigobarras").submit(function(){
                     return false;
                   });
                    //Tu función se llama compruebaCodigo funcionDeValidar($(this).val());
                      compruebaCodigo($(this).val());
                 }
             });

         });

         //En este caso como la url está como primer elemento, si le masdas el código lo toma como la url no como el código function compruebaCodigo(url, codigo){
           function compruebaCodigo(codigo){
                      $.ajax({
                url:'php/busqueda.php',
                type:'post',
                data:{ codigo: codigo},
                success: function(response){
                    if(response==2){
                        console.log("No tiene status aprobatorio"+response);
                    }
                    else if(response==3){
                    //aquí pondrías tu función o código que levanta la ventana modal
                        modal();//Se manda llamar la función
                    }else{
//Adicional puedes poner como un default, encaso de que no responda algo o se ocaionen errores en tu PHP
console.log("Hubo un error al procesar el código");
}
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>

    +----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Table          | Create Table |
    +----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
    | caratulasalida | CREATE TABLE `caratulasalida` (
      `net_app_po` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `costumer_np` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `rev` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `boxes_by_po` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `pallet_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `dn` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `create_date_asn` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `shipping_address` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `description` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `so_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=146 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
    +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que pruebes con evento`onchange`, que al momento de detectar un cambio en el input puedes llamar a una función que haga la validación que necesitas, también puede probar con el evento `onblur` con el cual también puedes llamar a una función, pero esta se ejecuta al momento de tu dejar de hacer focus en el input. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

tal vez no está muy clara tu pregunta, pero por lo que entiendo es que quieres validar el código de barras ingresado en el campo de texto sin necesidad de oprimir un botón, si es así, eso lo puedes hacer con javascript o más fácil utilizando jQuery, con el evento keypress, tengo entendido que los scaners de código de barras ya incluyen el enter, por lo tanto al cachar en enter puedes mandar llamar la función que va y valida en la base de datos: algo así

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#campotexto").keypress(function(even) {
     //Si fue enter    
     if(even.which == 13) {
         funcionDeValidar($(this).val());      
      }
     });

});

     
function funcionDeValidar(valor){
  alert("Valor a validar: "+ valor);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="campotexto" type="text" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

Desconozco como realices el llamado, pero ya sea que uses aJax u otro método, eso te puede funcionar.

Para las consultas puedes probar un procedimiento almacenado que te valide las dos tablas pasando como parámetro el código algo así.

```
    create procedure validaCodigo(in codigo int)
          begin
            if exists(select status from Tabla1 where campoCodigo = codigo and status=3) then 
                if exists(select status from Tabla2 where campoCodigo = codigo) then 
                   select 3 as respuesta;
                else
                   select 2 as respuesta;  
                end if;
            else
                select 2 as respuesta; 
            end if;
          end
```

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#campotexto").keypress(function(even) {
     //Si fue enter    
        if(even.which == 13) {
            compruebaCodigo(valida.php,$(this).val());          
      }
     });

});

function compruebaCodigo(url,codigo){
        $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:"POST",
                data:{ codigo: codigo},

                success: function(response){

                    if(response==2){

                        alert("No tiene status aprobatorio");
                    }
                    else if(response==3){
                        //aquí pondrías tu función o código que levanta la ventana modal
                    }   
                }
            });

            return false;
    }
```

así podría quedar tu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#codigo").keypress(function(even) {
            //Si fue enter
            if(even.which == 13) {
                funcionDeValidar($(this).val());
             }
         });

     });

     function compruebaCodigo(url,codigo){
        $.ajax({
            url:php/busqueda.php,
            type:"POST",
            data:{ codigo: codigo},
            success: function(response){
                if(response==2){
                    alert("No tiene status aprobatorio");
                }
                else if(response==3){
                //aquí pondrías tu función o código que levanta la ventana modal
                    modal();//Se manda llamar la función
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

 //Se declara la fucnión
function modal(){
    $('#modalserial').on('shown.bs.modal',function () {
    $('#modalserial').trigger('focus')});
}
</script>
```

**Tu código correjido**

```
<form id="codigobarras" class="codigo">
        <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" placeholder="Escanear Codigo de Barras del DN" class="codigo" />
        <!--El onkeypres no lo creo necesario, ya que estarías validando dos veces. -->
</form>


    <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3>Cabecera de la ventana</h3>
             </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>por fin apareci ahora si ya ponme lo que quieras hacer...</p>
             </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar</a>
             </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#codigo").keypress(function(even) {
                //Si fue enter
                //no se 3 es 13 if(even.which == 3) {
                  if(even.which == 13) {
                   //Como tu input lo tienes en un formulario, cuando oprimes enter sometes el formulario y te recarga la página,
                   //con esto puedes evitar eso.
                   $("#codigobarras").submit(function(){
                     return false;
                   });
                    //Tu función se llama compruebaCodigo funcionDeValidar($(this).val());
                      compruebaCodigo($(this).val());
                 }
             });

         });

         //En este caso como la url está como primer elemento, si le masdas el código lo toma como la url
         //no como el código function compruebaCodigo(url, codigo){
           function compruebaCodigo(codigo){
                      $.ajax({
                url:'php/busqueda.php',
                type:'post',
                data:{ codigo: codigo},
                success: function(response){
                    if(response==2){
                        console.log("No tiene status aprobatorio"+response);
                    }
                    else if(response==3){
                    //aquí pondrías tu función o código que levanta la ventana modal
                        modal();//Se manda llamar la función
                    }else{
                        //Adicional puedes poner como un default, encaso de que no responda algo o se ocaionen errores en tu PHP
                        console.log("Hubo un error al procesar el código");
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

**Captura de las pruebas que realizé**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ejmplo de conexión a MySQL en PHP**
**conexion.php**

```
<?php 
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $bd="BD";
    $pass="******";

    $conexion =@mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$bd);
    // if(!$conexion){
    //  echo "Error al conectar";
    // }
    // else{
    //  echo "Conectado";
    // }

 ?>
```

**registro.php**

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';

$error;

insertar_marca($conexion);

function insertar_marca($conexion)
{
    global $error;

    $nombre_marca = strtoupper($_POST["nombre-marca"]);
    $insertar ="call registrar_marca ('$nombre_marca')";

    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
    $resultado=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if (!$query){
        $error=0;
    }
    else{
        if($resultado['error']==1){
            $error=2;
        }
        else{
            $error=1;
        }
    }
    return $error;
}

echo $error;


 ?>
```

Comment: si entiendo como funciona el enter de escaner ahora te actualize la pregunta añadiendo la consulta a la bd lo que pasa es que no se como hacer bien las consultas y hacer lo que te menciono al inicio de la pregunta, el detalle es solo escanear el codigo de barras y al mismo tiempo hacer la comparacion si tiene estatus 3 y si ese codigo esta en el plan diario continua abriendo una ventana y si no solo que mande una alerta

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta, puse un procedimiento almacenado que puedes usar para hacer los dos comparaciones, la respuesta la recibes y si no es igual con 3 puedes mandar el alert que quieres de lo contrario, mostrar la otra ventana.

Comment: entiendo bien la consulta pero el detalle es como la puedo implementar en mi consulta, los campos que utilizo son el `dn` es donde esta el codigo, `pallet_status` donde esta los estatus que deve de ser 3 aprueba 2 no pasa estos estan en la tabla caratulasalida y en la tabla plandiario tambien es `dn` y despues de eso como lo puedo inclui en el javascript... estoy mas perdido que un calcetin en la lavadora :(

Comment: Si estas utilizando ajax  es fácil, puedes poner tu llamado al archivo PHP en la fucnión de ejemplo, enviando el código que fue introducido en el compo de texto, en tu PHP envez de hacer tu consulta que tienes, realiza la consulta de solo llamar al procedimiento enviando como parametro lo que enviaste en ajax y recibes la respuesta y la procesas directamente en javascript.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta, checa la parte final, te puse un ejemplo.

Comment: bien gracias en un momento lo armo ya me di a la idea de como hacerlo ahora si muchaas gracias por tu cooperacion...

Comment: Para eso estamos, cuando lo realices no olvides compartir si tuviste éxito. Saludos.

Comment: hola @Jesús Petrona Castro ya actualize la pregunta añadi la consulta y si me funciona ya la probe en la consola de sql ahora lo que no me funciona es el javascript para poder sacar la venta modal.... me podrias echar una mano con eso

Comment: Hola nuevamente, al parecer ya lo tienes, solo es un pequeño detalle, en tu bloque donde pones tu función  para abrir ventana modal, sólo estás declarando la función, pero no veo que la mandes llamar, te aconsejaría que en vez de declarar ahí la función, solo mandes llamar y la declaración la podrías hacer por fuera, dejo el ejemplo en la respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: ya hice lo que me aconsejas y de echo modifique el llamado a la ventana modal por que lo tenia mal pero no me muestra nada... ni la alerta ni la ventana :*(

Comment: Puedes probar imprimiendo el response, para ver qué valor te está regresando, te recomiendo un console.log("Resultado del llamado"+response) y pruebas abriendo la consola del explorador para que debugges, algunas veces tienes que borrar el histotal del explorardor para eliminar caché y poder  ver los resultados en los scripts. Me comentas qué tal.

Comment: ya hice todo eso de echo siempre antes de probar el sistema le doy ctrl + F5 para limpiara la cache y en el explorador del navegador solo me marca que carga el jquery y cuando mando un codigo para que me haga el proceso me marca un pequeño error pero es demaciado rapido para verlo se quita rapidamente

Comment: Dónde te aparece el error, ¿si te llega lo que envías en tu archivo PHP?, los errores de script siempre están en la consola, no se si puedes mandar alguna imagen para verificar.

Comment: no, no me llego ningun archivo, el detalle que no me muestra ningun error, en la consola cuando cargo la pagina solo carga el jquery y bootstrap y al momento de hacer la accion de mandar el codigo no detecta el ajax y entra a la pagina de busqueda.php para realizar la consulta le puse onkeypres(); en el input text y unos alert al inicio de la funcion y si los detecta pero ya lo demas no

Comment: Puedes poner tu código para checarlo y así poder ver donde puede estar el detalle, ya que por lo menos te tiene que llegar a tu PHP lo que envías.

Comment: listo esta todo lo que tengo ...

Comment: Hola colega, edite tu código, checa los comentarios y los ajustes en tu pregunta, checalos y me comentas, sólo una duda, donde haces la referencia al jquery?

Comment: Los correcciones las puse en la respuesta, puedes checarlas ahí, creo no se van a ver los cambios en tu pregunta.

Comment: puessss no pasa absolutamente nada, no manda ni error, ni las alertas del console.log, no pasa nada de echo ya ni refresca la pagina nada... :(

Comment: Tengo la duda de donde estás declarando la referencia a tu jQuery, ¿Lo obtienes desde una ruta relativa o absoluta? es decir, tienes el archivo en una carpeta en tu servidor local, o como una ruta de internet? y ya no refresca la página porque con lo anterior lo que hacías era someter el formulario y no hacía nada, solo se actualizaba la página, yo brobé el código y me respondió sin problemas.

Comment: lo tengo absoluta en una carpeta 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css"> <script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery.js" ></script>
ya logre que me marcara un error en consola por que mi llamado de la ventana modal esta mal... con todo y ventana modal te responde bien, y haciendo llamada a base de datos?? te invite a un chat no te llego invitacion??